# using combo box values by using id's

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox with values like members, payments, visits like....

we can do like this

```
        if(combobox.text = "members")
        {
                \\do something...
        }



        if(combobox.text = "visits")
        {
                \\do something...
        }

       if(combobox.text = "payments")
        {
                \\do something...
        }
```

we can do like this but i dont want to hardcode like this 
 is there any other way to use combo box values with their id's not using text like the above mentioned

can any one help on this ....

Comment: It depends on how you are populating the ComboBox values, can you include the code that fills the ComboBoxes? Or did you type the values in through the designer?

Comment: I have typed the values in through the designer

Comment: Just a suggestion, might be more readable to use a switch statement rather than lots of ifs

Comment: On a side note, your comment slashes are backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the alternative is to fill the combo box with items which have value and text and these could be, for example, two columns of a table in the database.

In this way in the loading of the items there is no hard coded data and you can load more items (or simply different ones) by editing the data in that database table.

if the number of items is very limited you can also create an enum and use the enum values to verify what is the currently selected value, with some modifications of the code you have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx

You can attach any object to every item, along with the text, and then get the selected item, extract the object, cast it to the type you *know* it is, and then get your data from there...

Oh, and you might want to consider some advice: populate the combobox in C# code, not manually in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways if your values are comming from a datasource or or something. Since these look like static commands which won't change much, there really might not be a much cleaner way to do it.

I agree with @Manatherin's comment, you should do it in a switch statement. I would include and else clause that throws an exception, so you know if you mistyped the value text or something.